# potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

i have a form that render a table with a hidden field values and run Document Ready this page.

hidden fields values that fill in code behind in pageload is:

```
<div 
    onclick="GetIcon(this)" style="cursor:pointer;" 
    URL=~\App_Images\Gallery\MapIcons\administrativeboundary.png >

    <img 
        src=../App_Images/Gallery/MapIcons/administrativeboundary.png 
        title="administrativeboundary"/>
</div>
#
<div 
    onclick="GetIcon(this)" 
    style="cursor:pointer;" 
    URL=~\App_Images\Gallery\MapIcons\administrativeboundary.png >

    <img src=../App_Images/Gallery/MapIcons/administrativeboundary.png 
        title="administrativeboundary"/>
</div>#
```

my functions page load is :

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
            RendertblConstantsColumns('tbl_Gallery', 5, 'GColumn');
            RenderGalleryTable();
        });

function RendertblConstantsColumns(tblid, ColumnNo, Columnid) {
    var tblConstants = document.getElementById(tblid);
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tblConstants.appendChild(tr);
    for (var i = 0; i < ColumnNo; i++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: right');
        td.setAttribute('id', Columnid + i.toString());
        tblConstants.appendChild(td);
    }
}
        function RenderGalleryTable() {

            var Gallery = document.getElementById("<%=hdnGallery.ClientID%>");
            var Images = Gallery.value.split('#');

            for (var i = 0; i < Images.length - 1; i++) {
                var Mode = i % 5;
                var Column = document.getElementById('GColumn' + Mode.toString());
                Column.innerHTML += Images[i];
            }
        }
```

i set ValidateRequest="false" And EnableEventValidation="false" this page but when get page run, show this error message:

```
potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client
```

my stack trace is:

```
at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Item(String key)
   at ASP.global_asax.Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

EDIT:
I fill hidden field Like this in server:

```
string HTML = "";
HTML += "<div onclick=\"GetIcon(this)\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\"" + " URL=" + URL + " ><img " + "src=../App_Images/Gallery/MapIcons/" + ImageName + " " + "title=\"" + ImageName.Split('.')[0] + "\"" + "/></div>#";

hdnGallery.Value = HTML;
```

Comment: write this <system.web><requestValidationMode="2.0" /></system.web> in ur config file.

Comment: then plz upvote my comment....

Comment: feeling great that it worked for u..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make required settings in web.config file :-

```
<system.web>
    <requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the solution is to HTML encode the offending data which is being sent to the server.

Since the error occurs on run, try and identify the line of code triggering the error, probably from javascript.